# Avoid using temp files for pr

Tags: scripting, pr

I am tailing two files at the same time, side by side, I can't get a version to work that doesn't use temporary files `F1.tmp` and `F2.tmp`. 
I would like to use watch to call this script.

Pretty sure I am missing something about command expansion and piping outputs.

```
FNAME1="$(ls -t | grep '.out'|  head -n2 | sort | head -n1)"
FNAME2="$(ls -t | grep '.out'|  head -n2 | sort | tail -n1)"
KEY="TIME STEP ="
TS1=`grep "$KEY" "$FNAME1" | tail -n 3`
TF1=`tail -n40  "$FNAME1"`
F1="$FNAME1""$TS1""$TF1\n"

TS2=`grep "$KEY" "$FNAME2" | tail -n 3`
TF2=`tail -n40  "$FNAME2"`
F2="$FNAME2\n\n$TS2\n\n$TF2\n"
echo "$FNAME1" > F1.tmp
echo "$TS1" >> F1.tmp
echo "$TF1" >> F1.tmp
echo "$FNAME2" > F2.tmp
echo "$TS2" >> F2.tmp
echo "$TF2" >> F2.tmp
pr -m -W 144 F1.tmp F2.tmp




pr -m -W 144 <(echo "$TS1") <(echo "$TS2")
```

Doesn't work

```
pr -m -W 144 <($TS1) <($TS2)
```

Doesn't either.
For context this is used to monitor CFD output files running on an HPC cluster.

below works on its own, but not when called using watch:

```
FNAME1="$(ls -t | grep '.out'|  head -n2 | sort | head -n1)"
FNAME2="$(ls -t | grep '.out'|  head -n2 | sort | tail -n1)"
KEY="TIME STEP ="
TS1=`grep "$KEY" "$FNAME1" | tail -n 3`
TF1=`tail -n40  "$FNAME1"`
F1="$FNAME1\n\n$TS1\n\n$TF1\n"

TS2=`grep "$KEY" "$FNAME2" | tail -n 3`
TF2=`tail -n40  "$FNAME2"`
F2="$FNAME2\n\n$TS2\n\n$TF2\n"
pr -m -W 144 <(printf "$F1") <(printf "$F2")
```

Seams to work ok on putty, juice ssh makes a mess of the formatting of you change the font size.

Note: I'm searching for occurrences of '$KEY' in the file '$FNAME1'.

Comment: Do you intend on tailing the files continuously or just fetching certain lines ? If just a few lines, it seems like it could be made a lot simpler.

Comment: Currently I'm using watch to run this script continuously. I think I've fixed it, partly due to juice ssh messing about with the formatting.

Comment: `TS1` declaration seems wrong. If you intended on filtering  contents of `FNAME` variable, then it should be `grep "$KEY" <<< "$FNAME1"` if your shell is bash, or just pipe if that's `/bin/sh` shell

Comment: @sergiy I'm searching for occurrences of '$KEY' in the file '$FNAME1'